# Is there a library for converting Wavefront .obj files to XAML?

Tags: .net, xaml, 3d, wavefront

I have a large number of [Wavefront .obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files that I need to convert to XAML `MeshGeometry3D` elements. I can do this manually by importing them in Microsoft Expression Blend and copying the XAML, but it would help greatly if I could automate the process.

Are there any libraries (preferably .NET, but I'll take anything) to do this?

Comment: As OBJ files are rather easy to read, I guess you could simply write it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This toolkit has almost everything you would need: http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/